# Noether's Theorem in non-conservative systems

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

In most books on classical mechanics, [Noether's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) is only formulated in  conservative systems with an action principle. Therefore I was wondering if it is possible to also do that in non-conservative systems? It would be pretty cool if you could at least get the conservation of momentum (which is valid also in non-conservative systems if there are no external forces because of Newton 3) from translation symmetry and conservation of angular momentum (which is also valid in non-conservative systems as long as there are only central forces) as a consequence of rotation symmetry in non-conservative systems. If that is not the case, is there any way to extend Hamilton's principle or the generelization of it ($\int  (\delta T + \delta W) dt = 0$, see for example Sommerfeld) so that it also covers Newton 3 (also maybe that's a topic worthy of its own question)?

Comment: One article that might be interesting is Galley's 2014 paper [The principle of stationary nonconservative action
for classical mechanics and field theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3082).  IT develops a way to approach arbitrary non-conservative effects withint leaving Lagrangian mechanics.  This is likely to help.  Obviously you wont find a conservation law when there is no conservation, but if the non-conservative elements are unaffected by your symmetry, it might work.

Comment: Related: [Does Noether's Theorem Apply in Galley's Extension to Lagrangian Mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/568199/2451)